# how to call html file in tinymce, edit and then update the file to save

Tags: php, jquery

I am new in php,and I want to use tinymce editor,
I wants to open my html file in tinymce editor and after editing I want to save it,

Below is the code for including tinymce editor

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    <script>
```

please help me how to do this.

Comment: Do you want to **need** to use jQuery with AJAX for that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to look into [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) for that.

You can send it through AJAX by doing something like this (Assuming that's what you want):

```
// Replace .save-button with whatever button you use
$('.save-button').click(function()
{
    var contents = tinyMCE.get('id-of-editor').getContent();

    $.post('save_html_file.php', { content: contents }, function(data)
    {
        // Callback
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

use getContent() function, update your textarea and submit form
here is a useful link
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent

example

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    $("#yourTextArea").value( tinyMCE.get('content id').getContent() );
});
```